# Html canvas element's getImageData doesn't match content of Fabricjs canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I added a fabric Rect at (80, 80) and then called getImageData at that location. However, the data I get from that location doesn't match the Rect I placed there. Instead, I find the data around (60, 60).

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric-canvas');
canvas.setHeight(800);
canvas.setWidth(800);

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 80,
  top: 80,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 20,
  height: 20
});
canvas.add(rect);

// This doesn't work
let data = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(80, 80, 20, 20);
canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(data, 0, 0);

// This "works"
data = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(60, 60, 20, 20);
canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(data, 100, 0);
```

Here's a fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2wxdb8ua/13/

How might this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is certainly caused by some zooming, either due to your monitor  being an high-res monitor (a.k.a retina), or browser/OS zoom being applied on the page.

You can either make the calculation yourself `world_coord * window.devicePixelRatio`:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric-canvas');
canvas.setHeight(800);
canvas.setWidth(800);

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 80,
  top: 80,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 20,
  height: 20
});

canvas.add(rect);

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(...[80, 80, 20, 20].map(fixCoords));
canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(ctx, ...[0, 0].map(fixCoords));

function fixCoords( coord ) {
  return coord * window.devicePixelRatio;
}
```

```css
canvas#fabric-canvas {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='fabric-canvas'></canvas>
```

Or disable fabric's auto-scaling by using the `enableRetinaScaling` parameter of the *initOptionObject*:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric-canvas', {
  enableRetinaScaling: false
});
canvas.setHeight(800);
canvas.setWidth(800);

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 80,
  top: 80,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 20,
  height: 20
});

canvas.add(rect);

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(80, 80, 20, 20);
canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(ctx, 0, 0);
```

```css
canvas#fabric-canvas {
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='fabric-canvas'></canvas>
```

But note that with the latter solution, your canvas will certainly become blurry on high-res monitors.